# shellescape package manipulation to get 3 pdf

Tags: compiling, multiple-files

windows 10 / TexMaker / Miktex distribution
Hello. I have a document which looks like the example follow :

```
   \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{shellesc}

\ifx\conditionmacro\undefined
  \ShellEscape{%
    lualatex --jobname="\jobname1"
    "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{1}\string\input\space\jobname"
  }%
  \ShellEscape{%
    lualatex --jobname="\jobname2"
    "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{2}\string\input\space\jobname"
  }%
  \ShellEscape{%
    lualatex --jobname="\jobname3"
    "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{3}\string\input\space\jobname"
  }%
  \expandafter\stop
\fi



\begin{document}
\ifnum\conditionmacro=1%
\section{P1}
\newpage
\section{P2}
\newpage
\fi
\ifnum\conditionmacro=2%

\section{P3}
\fi
\newpage
\ifnum\conditionmacro=3%

\section{corr}
\fi

\end{document}
```

ATM when I compile i get 3 PDF : #1 has section1&2 , #2 has section 3 and #3 has section CORR.  I would like to change this behavior :  PDF 1# should have the whole document , PDF#2 and #3 remains what they are. Is it possible ? I wasn't able to manipulate the shellescape lines.

Comment: This (and the one you linked to) really aren't looking for 1 compilation.  You're looking for different pdfs from the same basic file, based on slight changes (and sometimes using some slight of hand to get multiple compilations from one).  It seems like you could use the `ifthen` package to simplify your conditionals, so that `if conditionmacro is 1 or 2`, then you'd get sections 1--3, and `if conditionmacro is 1 or 3`, then you'd get section 4.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, i'm asking LaTeX to do something like 3 compilations but with 1 command. I think i didn't understood what u mean with the ifthen package

Comment: The `ifthen` package would let you do something like `\ifthenelse{ \conditionmacro=1 \OR \conditionmacro=2 }{ \section{1} \section{2} \section{3} }{}`.

Comment: i edited the first message. I managed to improve the code (i mean, closer to what i need). I think it's AND / OR thing now, i'd like to get Jobname1 with all the document, Jobname2 and 3 are fine

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  It would be helpful to know which platform you are on. If you are on MacOS, I would use TeXShop and set up a custom `.engine` file tha produces all three pdfs for you when you hit the `Typeset` button.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on windows with TexMaker and Miktech

Comment: You can try this new pacakge  https://ctan.org/pkg/conditext

Comment: @rpapa i read, but it won't help me getting 2-3 PDF in the end. :/